# How to use array of addresses to lock cells in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a list of cells in an Excel spreadsheet from which I defined an array.
I want to loop through this list and set the corresponding cells to unlocked. However, I keep getting "Error: Object required" (translated from German). Can anyone help?

```
Sub LockCells()

Dim CellList as Variant
CellList = Array("A2", "A8", "B4")

For Each cell in CellList
    Sheets("MySheet").Range(cell).Locked = False
Next cell

End Sub
```

(The line inside the loop works if I hardcode cell to be one of the array elements.)

Comment: No repro... but better to use a `For` loop to iterate an array than a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit`, see [this explanation](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) -- so define `Dim cell As Variant` before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testRangeFromArray()
  Dim CellList As Variant
  CellList = Array("A2", "A8", "B4")
  Sheets("MySheet").Range(Join(CellList, ",")).Locked = False
End Sub
```

Or directly:

```
Sheets("MySheet").Range("A2, A8, B4").Locked = False
```

But, if you like an iteration, please use (declare the iteration variable like `Variant`):

```
Sub testRangeFromArray_()
  Dim CellList As Variant, El As Variant
  CellList = Array("A2", "A8", "B4")
  For Each El In CellList
     Sheets("MySheet").Range(El).Locked = False
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Using the first variant, I now get the error message "unable to set the Locked property of the Range class" although I use Worksheet("MySheet").Unprotect in my code.

Comment: @painfulenglish: This is not connected to the code working way...  `Worksheet("MySheet")` does not make sense. It must be `Worksheets("MySheet")`. But, maybe you made the mistakes only here. Try, please: `Sheets("MySheet").Range("A2").Locked = False`. Didn't it return the same error? Visually check if the sheet is unprotected. Is your real sheet name "MySheet"?

Comment: That was a typo (I did not copy/paste the code). I found the problem: one of the cells I wanted to unlock was a joined cell. Using "B4:D4" instead of "B4" made everything work!

Answer (score 0):

Just convert cell to string with `CStr()`

```
Sheets("MySheet").Range(CStr(cell)).Locked = False
```

Comment: But if you add `Debug.Print Typename(cell)` inside the loop, the result is `String` already.